# Can empty space be a frame of reference to measure velocity?

Tags: acceleration, velocity, inertial-frames

I am wondering if there is only one object in the universe than does it make any sense to talk about its velocity. If empty space can be thought of as a reference to measure its velocity than it might.

I read somewhere that in empty space someone cannot tell if she is moving unless she has some acceleration. Now if it does not make sense to talk about velocity how can it make sense to talk about acceleration?

Comment: "If it does not make sense to talk about velocity, how can it make sense to talk about acceleration?" This is a classic example of how using sketchy intuition can lead you off a cliff. The two quantities only look similar because they both have to do with motion. Otherwise they're totally different.

Comment: It's the same as with perpetual motion machines... the day somebody builds one scientists will find a way to describe its principles. If somebody finds a way to link absolute motion to absolute space somehow... we'll learn how to describe that. So far nobody has found a way, so we don't have to. Acceleration, on the other hand, can be measured with an accelerometer. Cheap ones can be had for something like 50 cents these days.

Comment: If space is empty, what are you going to "refer" to?

Comment: Does acceleration mean something other than rate of change of velocity with respect to time in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Equivalence Principle of General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) holds that acceleration and gravity can be described identically.  With an accelerometer, you can tell whether or not you are accelerating in empty space, regardless of whether another object is available to act as a reference point.  Under acceleration, your weight will change just as though you were approaching or standing in a gravitational field.

Velocity, however, has meaning only in relation to relative movement between two or more objects.  No one has yet discovered an edge to empty space which can be used as a reference point for measuring the velocity of an object.  Therefore, a reference point is necessary to measure velocity, and the velocity will be attributable to both objects.

Acceleration is the rate of change of velocity.  You do not need to know the magnitude of velocity, only its rate of change in order to measure acceleration.

Comment: So here something cannot be measured and it is meaningless  but it's rate of change can be measured. It is kind of hard to grasp. It seems to me that acceleration is more fundamental than velocity or something like that.

Comment: @IbraheemMoosa:  Velocity can be measured.  It is not meaningless.  But it can be measured only by comparison to an object in a different inertial frame.  Acceleration can be measured without reference to a different inertial frame.

Comment: When there is a different inertial frame velocity and acceleration are both meaningful. When there cannot be one only acceleration is meaningful.

Comment: @IbraheemMoosa: It's not quite like that. If there is no second frame, then velocity is only defined up to a constant which has no measurable physical effects. Its change is still defined, so after an acceleration event you can always tell that relative to the frame you have been in you are now moving at a well defined velocity. Inertial guidance systems are based on that principle and before GPS they were used to get a plane within a couple of miles of its target airport without anybody having to look out of the window to find way markers in the landscape.

Comment: I think I understand it now. After an acceleration event you can always measure velocity relative to the reference frame you were in.

Comment: And as long as change of velocity can be defined, acceleration can be defined.