# Given a proton in an otherwise empty universe can it move

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity

Given a proton in an otherwise empty universe can it move.  If it is said to move, will it create a magnetic field.

Comment: This is a duplicate is a number of questions which have been answered in this site. Put "empty space frame of reference" in the search engine. For example https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233217/104696, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1372/104696 etc.

Answer (score 3):

This question, of course, requires the introduction of some sort of reference frame. If we were to choose to observe the proton in a reference frame stationary with respect to the proton, naturally there would be no magnetic field. However, if we were to observe the proton in a reference frame moving with respect to the proton, there would be a magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

It's a senseless question because even an observer will not fulfill the definition of an empty space.

Furthermore an electron in an empty space hasn't any reference frame and by this the movement or standstill of the electron hasn't any significance.

IF there is a measuring instrument (the observer) this instrument will be influenced by the moving electron and a magnetic field will be induced in the instrument. Without the inducable instrument you will not be able to detect any magnetic field.

Comment: I agree, to make sense of the universe we need two objects or one object and a reference frame.  So movement is position of one object RELATIVE to another.

Comment: So now we have movement do we have TIME.